# How can I Format systemctl --type=service output into csv

Tags: linux, shell, sed, systemctl

For example, the output for

`systemctl --type=service`

is something like this:

```
Unit                    Load   Active SUB      Description
abrt-ccpp.service       loaded active exited   Install ABRT coredump hook
abrt-oops.service       loaded active running  ABRT kernel log watcher
```

How can I turn this into a csv that looks more like this?

```
Unit,Load,Active,SUB,Description
abrt-ccpp.service,loaded,active,exited,"Install ABRT coredump hook"
abrt-oops.service,loaded,active,running,"ABRT kernel log watcher"
```

I tried to use **sed** to get rid of the spaces with something like this:

```
$ sed 's/ \{1,\}/,/g' file
```

as expected the problem with this is the Description column is also being split with commas.

So I thought of removing the description column with awk, and maybe just get the description separately and append it later.

```
systemctl --type=service | awk '!($5="")'
```

This only removed the header "Description", all it's contents were still in the output.

Is there a better/easier way to get a list of all the services and it's status if it's running or not? Or even just a list of running services that can be put in a csv.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (output of only running services):

```bash
systemctl --type=service|awk '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4}'|grep running
```

this will output something like:

```bash
accounts-daemon.service,loaded,active,running
acpid.service,loaded,active,running
avahi-daemon.service,loaded,active,running
bluetooth.service,loaded,active,running
...
```

you could use regex to also capture the description, but I do not know if that is of any value to you.